# Avoid curve be trimmed in the plot in R

Tags: r, plot, histogram, probability

How is possible to avoid my curve (green line) be cut?

```
x <- Phoenix_August_clean$Sum.Precipitation.Total.August
curve(dnorm(x, mean = fit.gaussian2$estimate[1], sd = fit.gaussian2$estimate[2]), lwd=3, col="red", add=TRUE)
curve(dgamma(x, fit.gamma.mme$estimate[1], fit.gamma.mle$estimate[2]), col="orange", lwd=3, add=TRUE) #Maximum likelihood
curve(dgamma(x, fit.gamma.mme$estimate[1], fit.gamma.mme$estimate[2]), col="green", lwd=3, add=TRUE) #Method of moments
legend("topright",legend=c("Normal","Gamma - ML","Gamma - MM"), col=c("red","orange","green"), lty=1, lwd=1)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: The plot sets the `ylim` automatically based on the data presented in the first plotting function (allegedly some form of `hist`), but it is set before you add a line that goes outside the limits. Set `ylim=` manually.

Answer (score 1):

The limits are set on the first plot (apparently a call to `hist` for you) based on the data known at that time, so you need to set the `ylim=` yourself on *that* call, based on the curves you intend to plot.

Problem plot:

```r
hist(mtcars$disp, freq=FALSE)
curve(dgamma(x-100, 50)/10, lwd=3, col="red", to=500, add=TRUE)
```

[image: sample plot, curve off the page]

Fixed plot, adding `ylim=...` manually.

```r
hist(mtcars$disp, freq=F, ylim=c(0, 0.0055))
curve(dgamma(x-100, 50)/10, lwd=3, col="red", to=500, add=TRUE)
```

[image: sample plot, fixed]